# Macdeployqt: ERROR: no file at "/Users/michael/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick"

Tags: qt, macdeployqt

I recently updated from Qt 5.3 to Qt 5.5. Since the update, I can't seem to get `macdeployqt` to work properly. When I call it for my application, I get the following output:

```
Michaels-Mac-mini:Desktop michael$ ~/Qt/5.5/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt FlySightViewer.app
ERROR: Cannot resolve rpath "libvlc-qt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)"
ERROR:  using QSet("/Users/michael/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib")
ERROR: Cannot resolve rpath "libvlc-qt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)"
ERROR:  using QSet("/Users/michael/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib")
ERROR: no file at "/Users/michael/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick"
ERROR: no file at "/Users/michael/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml"
ERROR: no file at "/Users/michael/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork"
ERROR: no file at "/Users/michael/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui"
ERROR: no file at "/Users/michael/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore"
ERROR: no file at "/Users/michael/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets"
WARNING: Plugin "libqsqlodbc.dylib" uses private API and is not Mac App store compliant.
WARNING: Plugin "libqsqlpsql.dylib" uses private API and is not Mac App store compliant.
ERROR: no file at "/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib"
```

What catches my attention in particular are the six errors that refer to `~/Qt5.3.2/5.3`. This is where the old version of Qt was installed, but the only version I currently have installed is Qt 5.5. It seems like there is some reference in my project/system to the old version, but I have no idea where to look for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85369